# Uniqueness constraint exception not immediately triggered in test case

Tags: hibernate, unit-testing, jpa, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have a junit test to check that my uniqueness constraints are working correctly.  I'm finding that, after adding a duplicate entry, in order to get my expected exception I need to *either* make a db query or have @Rollback(false) set on the test.  (I'm guessing this is due to some sort of lazy commit logic?)

Is this expected?  Or is there a better way to write this test case?

```
@Test
@Rollback(false) // without this no duplicate is found.  Documentation and test1() don't accord with this. Why?
public void addDuplExchange() {
    exception.expect(DataIntegrityViolationException.class); //org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["UK_CI07R484MKOOCNBAD6Q6HG1DB_INDEX_2 ON PUBLIC.EXCHANGES(EXCHANGE_NAME_LOWERCASE) VALUES ('exchange3', 1)"; SQL statement:

    System.out.println("add dupl exchange...");
    ExchangeDbo e3a1 = dbService.addNewExchange("Exchange3");
    System.out.println(e3a1);
    ExchangeDbo e3a2 = dbService.addNewExchange("eXcHanGe3"); // this should fail
    System.out.println(e3a2);
    //      List<ExchangeDbo> x = dbService.getAllExchanges();
    //      x.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this expected?

Absolutely.

I assume that `dbService.addNewExchange()` calls `repository.save()` (which in turn calls `entityManager.persist()` internally). This only makes the newly created entity *managed*, meaning that its state will now be tracked by JPA. The state of this entity will be flushed to the db **when necessary, no later than upon transaction commit**.

> I need to either make a db query or have @Rollback(false) set on the test

By default, Hibernate executes flush upon transaction commit and before queries. The latter is to ensure changes made to the entities so far are reflected in query results.

To make the test fail, either switch to `repository.saveAndFlush()`, forcing a flush immediately, or flush the context explicitly by injecting an `EntityManager` into the test and calling `EntityManager.flush()` after both calls to `dbService.addNewExchange()` have been made.